# fit image to aspect ratio without croping it

Tags: php

I have an image with an aspect ratio of 9x16 (337px, 600px). I want to change the image 16x9 (1066px, 600px) permanently without cropping images using PHP
this is the example that i want [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSNSw.jpg) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjwrv.png).
Im Sorry i dont code yet because i don't know what i suppose to type to type on Google

```
$imagemal = "https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/1933/97061l.jpg";
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("$imagemal");
$newwidth = $height/9;
$newwidth = $newwidth*16;
$newwidth = round($newwidth);
```

Comment: if you want to just display it on 16x9 (1066px, 600px)  you need a css rule for that image, but if you want to generate a new image you need to create a new custom function http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Comment: This is not cropping, in fact, this is the opposite of cropping, you're PADDING the image, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058217/add-black-bars-to-create-a-16x9-image) will help?

Comment: hi @zack6849 thanks for your help :)